# RSS feeds not showing correctly (just text)

Tags: xml, rss

Here's an example of a Rss on my website:
http://www.dealinity.com/national.xml
I don't know why some RSS validator don't valid it, and Google Chrome nor Google Reader accept it either.
I did add header('Content-Type: text/xml'); and the type of it still text/html.
I hope you can find a solution for me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, validators are normal [pretty specific](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dealinity.com%2Fnational.xml) about why they don't validate things. And Google Reader didn't have a problem subscribing to your feed when I just tried it. I think you're going to need to be more specific about what your problems are, and how you're generating your feed, preferably including the relevant source code. Your content is definitely being served as `text/html` from what I can see, and definitely should be something like `application/rss+xml` or `application/xml` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When I visited it the first line was "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" indicates that some information has already been sent to the browser before you start outputting the XML.

If you're using PHP make sure you haven't accidentally sent down some white space.